# i'm finding factorial of a number by loop method but when I am trying to run the code, there's an error as "i' cannot be resolved in a variable

Tags: java

```
package loops;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int factorial = 1;

        for(int i = n ; i>=1 ; i--); {

             factorial = factorial * i;

        }

        System.out.println(factorial);
    }

 }
```

Comment: `for(int i = n ; i>=1 ; i--);`, remove the semicolon `;` at the end, you only use brackets for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program contains a `;` next to a for loop which causes the loop variable `i` to be not in scope of the factorial equation defined in your program. Remove the `;` and it should work.

Comment: there is another error that resource leak, sc variable is not closed....it shows the ans as follows5
5
20
60
120
120

Comment: Yes you should close the Scanner. But that is not the reason why you got o/p like that. Did you try printing value of factorial inside for loop. If yes, then make your loop go to `i >= 2` and it will show only one 120. By the way first 5 would be your i/p.